# how to add 'bikeport' to 7x7 plastic / resin shed

Tags: mounting, shed

I have a 7x7 resin / plastic shed. How can i add a 'bikeport' to side?  Especially how to attach it to the current shed.  Was thinking about getting one of those plastic fences and taking the planks off of it and using as a roof for 'bikeport'.  How to attach though to current shed?  Current shed is on very sturdy 2x6 pressure treated base.  By 'bikeport', I mean a side structure attached to the shed, like a carport, but smaller.  A roof structure that is otherwise open but supported by posts.

[image]

Comment: What is a bikeport? If you mean just a shed roof, use those terms instead. Otherwise, please describe or link to a description so we understand your goals.

Comment: So a "bike port" is an additional shed roof that you want to attach to the side of the existing shed. Is it something you're building yourself? Is it a pre-fab thing you're buying? In either case, drill holes through the side of the "port" roof, drill matching holes through the shed wall, put a washer on a bolt, slide the bolt through the holes, put another washer on, apply a nut - tighten snugly, but not so tight that you deform the plastic walls.

Comment: I would back the mount with plywood or lumber. That plastic is sure to deform, if not initially, over time. I'd like to know more, though.

Comment: ideally it will not have sides - just the roof.  Possibly i can drill holes in existing roof of shed and attach.  ill know more soon as I start.

Comment: There are so many different styles of bike ports it would be hard to say how you would mount it some are open that have a roof and the metal loop to lock the bike to, some are plastic boxes with doors, others look to be tent like, I am sure machine bolts with fender washers would work. I suggest fender washers to prevent the bolt head from being pulled through the plastic. Anything more than that we would need to see what kind of bike port you plan on joining to your shed.